# How closure causes js memory leak

Tags: javascript, closures

Could someone explaine to me why below code does **not** cause any memory leaks? My understanding is variable originalThing is being used in closure unCalled and theroetically referenced by closure someMethod, hence originalThing should not be garbage collected, but i do not see memory leak at all when i was profiling it in browser.

```
<script>
var theThing = new Array(1000000000);
var replaceThing = function () {
  var originalThing = theThing;
 
  var unCalled = function () {
    if (originalThing)
      return originalThing
  };
  var obj = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
    someMethod: function () {}
  };
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
</script>
```

But if i changed variable obj to theThing then it would cause memory leak, please see code below:

```
<script>

var theThing = new Array(1000000000);
var replaceThing = function () {
  var originalThing = theThing;
 
  var unused = function () {
    if (originalThing)
      console.log("Hi")
  };
   theThing = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
     someMethod: function () {}
  };
 
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 1000);
</script>
```

So what difference deos it make in terms of memory leak caused by closure?

Comment: Memory leak is the *accumulation* of extraneous objects in memory. This code doesn't cause accumulation - `theThing` is a single object. At most *it* stays around, not progressively more copies of stuff.

Comment: @VLAZ, then why the second script caused memory leak, the only difference is i replaced var obj with global variable theThing.

Comment: [It doesn't?](https://i.imgur.com/8Gg1pp8.png)

Comment: The second one DOES cause memory leak, but it could be fixed by removing someMethod from theThing object, i do not understand why....

Comment: [Here is a snapshot of the second code running for 60 seconds](https://i.imgur.com/HeisTeR.png). Again, I do not see a memory leak. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please refer to this post: https://blog.meteor.com/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak-8b47d2e7f156 I think 60 seconds is not long enough to see memory accumulation, it is better to profile allocation on timeline under memory tab, you would see theThing object would never be garbage collected as time goes.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant by providing all details, i think i have provided everything regarding to my questions above, here is the snapshot of second code https://imgur.com/a/as9rR8Y, it does cause memory leak due to closures.

Comment: Your initial question was why doesn't some code have a memory leak. Which turned out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as you actually wanted to know about another code. I tested it and there was no sign of a memory leak. Any time I comment, you come up with more and more information that *should have been in the question from the start*. All of those details are missing. Not "why there isn't a memory leak <code>".

Comment: The second code i post is my doubt to your first anwser....Anyway, thanks for your time.